# priority-web-sdk : Can I open 2 forms at once?

Tags: javascript, erp

Is there a way that 2 forms will be open at the same time, what about subforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start as many forms as you like..I'm talking about paretn forms. Just remember that each form you open will stay open until you close it.
For subforms it is a different story. You cannot work with more than one subform at the same time.
You must end a subform in order to start another one.